# Syntax errors when migrating a .bak created in SQLServer 2000 to SQLServer 2008 then to SQLServer 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

SQLServer 2012 sends me the syntax error while executing a stored procedure:

```
        where DOC.ID_DOC = @pi_ID_DOC
        and DOC.ID_DOC = DET.ID_DOC
        and DET.RECIBO_CONCEP = REC.RECIBO_CONCEP
        and DOC.CUENTA = CTO.CUENTA
        and DOC.CTA_CONSEC = CTO.CTA_CONSEC
        and CTA.CUENTA = CTO.CUENTA
        and DOC.CUENTA *= LEC.CUENTA
        and DOC.CTA_CONSEC *= LEC.CTA_CONSEC
        and DOC.BIMESTRE *= LEC.BIMESTRE
```

Especially while using the expresion "*=".

I executed the same stored procedure with no changes in SQLServer 2008 with no problems.

Does the '*=' have a meaning different from '='?
Are there changes in the syntax between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*=` (AND `=*`) is an outer join using the old-style syntax (syntax which is popular still in Oracle, but has been [deprecated since SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.100).aspx) and [officially discontinued in SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262(SQL.110).aspx)). This syntax is no longer supported and it has many problems. Some info here:

[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

You will need to re-write these queries into modern `LEFT / RIGHT JOIN` versions in order to make them compatible with SQL Server 2012. You should make new versions of the queries and keep the old versions, on your 2008 instance, so that you can validate that the re-writes return the correct results.

Erland Sommarskog has a guide that might help:

[Become an ANSI Star](http://www.sommarskog.se/Become-an-ANSI-star.doc)

[This MSDN forum thread might also be useful](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a843a7ae-3e09-4512-b453-7ad861824baa/converting-deprecated-outer-join-to-ansi-outer-join?forum=transactsql).